# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: /entirex/xml/mapping/jaxws_asm/package-info : Unsupported major.minor version 0.0

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, jboss7.x

I have created WS client from a WSDL using wsimport of jdk 1.7.
the client works fine when it is running as a standalone application .

When I run it on JBoss 7 I am getting :

[END]

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rqbalamWs/com/softwareag/namespace/entirex/xml/mapping/jaxws_asm/package-info : Unsupported major.minor version 0.0

      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)

      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper$TypeHelperClassLoader.defineClass(ASMHelper.java:367)

      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.loadClass(ASMHelper.java:316)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generatePackageInfo(WrapperClassGenerator.java:267)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:169)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generate(WrapperClassGenerator.java:122)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:683)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:653)

      at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:440)

      at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)

      at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)

      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)

      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)

      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:478)

      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.createPort(ProviderImpl.java:558)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)

      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:336)

      at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)

      at rqbalamWs.com.softwareag.namespace.entirex.xml.mapping.RQFXONLN.getDB2RQLIBSOAP11Port(RQFXONLN.java:72)

      at rqbalamWs.WsClient.send(WsClient.java:16)

      at calypsox.engine.FXBalamEngine.handlePSEventTrade(FXBalamEngine.java:87)

      at calypsox.engine.FXBalamEngine.process(FXBalamEngine.java:53)

      at com.calypso.engine.Engine$EngineThread.run(Engine.java:1413)
```

Does it means the in the classpath while running on JBoss , the Apache CXF jars  comes before the JDK WS implementaion , and this cause the error ? should I create the client using some  Apache CXF wizard (eclipse) instead of using wsimport ? if I will remove Apache CXF module from JBoss will it be ok ?

wsdl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
- <definitions name="RQFXONLN" targetNamespace="http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sn0="urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:DB2RQLIB" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
- <types>
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:DB2RQLIB">
- <xsd:element name="RQFXONLN">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="RQFXONLN_INPUT_DEAL" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="RQFXONLNResponse">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
- <xsd:element name="RQFXONLN_OUTPUT_RC">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
  <xsd:totalDigits value="5" />
  <xsd:fractionDigits value="0" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="RQFXONLN_OUTPUT_RC_INFO">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="70" />
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  </types>
- <message name="RQFXONLNSoapIn">
  <part name="parameters" element="sn0:RQFXONLN" />
  </message>
- <message name="RQFXONLNSoapOut">
  <part name="parameters" element="sn0:RQFXONLNResponse" />
  </message>
- <portType name="DB2RQLIBPort">
- <operation name="RQFXONLN">
  <input message="tns:RQFXONLNSoapIn" />
  <output message="tns:RQFXONLNSoapOut" />
  </operation>
  </portType>
- <binding name="DB2RQLIBSOAP11Binding" type="tns:DB2RQLIBPort">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
- <operation name="RQFXONLN">
  <soap:operation soapAction="RQFXONLN" />
- <input>
  <soap:body use="literal" />
  </input>
- <output>
  <soap:body use="literal" />
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
- <binding name="DB2RQLIBSOAP12Binding" type="tns:DB2RQLIBPort">
  <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
- <operation name="RQFXONLN">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="RQFXONLN" />
- <input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" />
  </input>
- <output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" />
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
- <service name="RQFXONLN">
- <port name="DB2RQLIBSOAP12Port" binding="tns:DB2RQLIBSOAP12Binding">
  <soap12:address location="http://entirextest:9080/wsstack/services/RQFXONLN.DB2RQLIBSOAP12Port/" />
  </port>
- <port name="DB2RQLIBSOAP11Port" binding="tns:DB2RQLIBSOAP11Binding">
  <soap:address location="http://entirextest:9080/wssta`enter code here`ck/services/RQFXONLN.DB2RQLIBSOAP11Port/" />
  </port>
  </service>
  </definitions>
```

Comment: Stacktrace would be very helpful here as it is not clear where the exception comes from. What CXF version do you use? The weird thing is the version number: 0.0. It suggests that problem is related to ASM library, see for example this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826302/java-asm-org-objectweb-asm-util-checkclassadapter-causes-unsupported-major-mino

Comment: thank you I will add Stacktrace  tomorrow

Comment: Code please. It looks Iike you're using a Javadoc .jar file rather than a .jar file of .class files.

Comment: please explain :It looks Iike you're using a Javadoc .jar file rather than a .jar file of .class files .   what code to pass ? all generated wsimport classes ? wsdl ?

Comment: Well certainly *not* the package-info file. That's part of the Javadoc.

Comment: I added the wsdl. The package-info file was generated for some reason by the wsimport . I deleted it now and try again to run on JBoss. can you please explain your remark about package-info file and javadoc ?

Comment: The package-info file is part of the Javadoc. No further explanation required.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and the problem seems to be related to wrong ASM library version.

Apache CXF uses ASM to generate classes. If you take a look at `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generatePackageInfo(String, String, Class<?>)` you will notice that Java version written to generated class is defined in `ASMHelper.Opcodes.V1_5`. However, CXF does not define constants in `ASMHelper.Opcodes` but loads it based on `Opcodes` class from ASM library. If this loading fails (e.g. because ASM `Opcodes` class is missing) then these properties remain 0 which leads to your problem (`Unsupported major.minor version 0.0`).

I was able to reproduce the problem with `asm:asm:1.5.3`.

To fix this you have to figure out why CXF picks wrong ASM library. Please check your EAR for obsolete asm jars. Maybe asm is loaded by JBoss which I doubt.

The best way to check where CXF takes ASM library from is to inject the following code to your app:

```
Method method = ASMHelper.class.getDeclaredMethod("getASMClass", null);
method.setAccessible(true);
Class asmClass = (Class) method.invoke(new ASMHelper(), null);
System.out.println("ASM location: " + asmClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
List<URL> classpaths = Arrays.asList(((URLClassLoader)asmClass.getClassLoader()).getURLs());
System.out.println("Classpath of classloader: " + classpaths);
```

Or use debugger to debug `org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.getASMClass()`